# Is it possible to have 2 functional SMS apps on KitKat?

Tags: android, sms, android-4.4-kitkat

I have an SMS popup app, that basically just lets me do quick replies and a few other minor custom things when an SMS comes in. I still use the default SMS app for pretty much everything, but my SMS popup app has the ability to (obviously) send out an SMS, and to mark an incoming SMS as read. Howeverm with all the SMS changes in KitKat, my app can no longer mark a message as read. It just silently fails (because it's not set as the default app, and so it has no write access to the SMS provider).

The problem is that I can't set my app as the default one because that would basically disable the actual regular SMS app that I'm using. So, is there any way to make my app functional while leaving the regular SMS app as the default?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

no it is not as explained in the [Android Developers Blog](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2013/10/getting-your-sms-apps-ready-for-kitkat.html) only one app can write to the database as the default sms app

Answer (score 4):

I have the exact same issue. There is this "non-user-friendly" possible workaround:
[How to write to SMS Content Provider in Android KitKat WITHOUT being default SMS app](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2551072)

otherwise, you may want to join the angry mob on google's android issue tracker:    [[NEW SMS API 4.4] Features request: SMS_RECEIVED_ACTION abortion enabled](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=61684)